# How can I select the largest value when an ungrouped column is dependent on a grouped column?

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I am new to Redshift. I have two tables, ticket_booking and ticket_review, the relation of the two tables is one - many. Which when combined looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5v7c.png]

The result I am looking for (I want to get the highest number per ticket_booking id) is:
[image]

I tried to obtain the desired result using the group by command to help distinct records. See script below:

```
select b.id, r.id, max(r.number) as revision_number
from dw.ticket_review as r, dw.ticket_booking as b
where r.ticket_booking_id = b.id
group by b.id
```

However, I get an error **column "r.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**. If I do this I get the result of the first picture. I tried different approaches mentioned in different questions but none seem to help me with my situation. Any help would be deeply appreciated! :)

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different database products.

Comment: Redshift, but isn't redshift based on Postgres? or at least that is how I understood it.

Comment: No, it was never "based" on Postgres. Amazon only used the SQL parser, essentially everything else is different. And even if they used more of that, both have diverged substantially.

Comment: Ohh! alright yes that makes sense, I took the tag out. Thank you for the clarification! :)

Comment: You're getting an error because you need both `b.id` and `r.id` in the `GROUP BY` clause. E.g. `GROUP BY b.id, r.id`

Comment: Hi Ricardo, unfortunately, if I include the r.id in the GROUP BY clause then the result I get is the one shown in the first picture. I think a subquery is a way but I can't figure it out yet. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per booking assign [row number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) ordering from highest review, then pick first rows only:

```
select booking_id, ticket_review, number
  from (select b.id as booking_id, r.id as ticket_review, r.number,
               row_number() over (partition by b.id order by r.id desc) rn
          from dw.ticket_review as r, dw.ticket_booking as b
         where r.ticket_booking_id = b.id) x
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Kombajn I cannot thank you enough. This worked brilliantly!